# ASP.NET_SessionId cookie for asp.net webform based website need GDPR compliance

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webforms

I have a website which where developed in **asp.net** webform few years back & due to GDPR compliance i am not sure `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie need user explicit permission.

Not sure what exactly `ASP.NET_SessionId cookie` is used it show for all asp.net website

Comment: The following URL links to information about asp.net core but you might find it helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @user1671787 - That is for .Net Core not for ASP.net.

Comment: Yes, as I stated originally it's about asp.net core.

Answer (score 1):

I will go out on a limb and give an in general response. This cookie should classified as a statistic cookie and should be strictly required thus eliminating the need for consent, however if it is tied to or can be corelated to any PII then the story changes.

No PII example :
IIS logs contain cookie values, ASP.Net_SessionID is logged and all other cookies are tokens or numerical anonymized values.

PII example :
IIS logs contain cookie values, ASP.Net_SessionID is logged along with another cookies that contains IP address, Userid, email, phone, etc...