# Why does ASP.NET SessionId cookie show for some website and not for all asp.net

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webforms

I have few old websites developed in asp.net webform .net framework 4.0.

Due to GDPRC compliance i noticed that some of the website show `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookies in developer/debugger tools but not for all how can we hide ASP.NET_SessionId for all website or is there a reason it is showing for some website and not for some

Comment: Duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50442773/asp-net-sessionid-cookie-for-asp-net-webform-based-website-need-gdpr-compliance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET\_SessionId cookie for asp.net webform based website need GDPR compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50442773/asp-net-sessionid-cookie-for-asp-net-webform-based-website-need-gdpr-compliance)